# I want to extract only the contents enclosed in tags using regular expressions

Tags: php, html, nsregularexpression

I have a text with <span> tags inserted.I want to use PHP to extract only the content enclosed in span from this text.I can't get the expected result. I would like to know what kind of regular expression I should use to get the expected result.

**[What I want to do]**

I want to extract only the contents of the egg tag.

**[Search target string]**

I ate a <span class="egg">boiled egg</span> and <span class="ham">ham</span>.

I ate a <span class="egg ham">ham and eggs</span>.

**[Regular expression]**

`(?<="|egg|">).+?(?=</span)`

**[Expected results]**

- boiled egg
- ham and eggs

**[Actual results]**

- egg">boiled egg and ham
- egg ham">ham and eggs

Comment: Try using DOMDocument instead, this understands the structure of the text (HTML) and can work a lot more reliablly.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

```
<span class=".*?egg.*?">(.+?)<\/span>
```

Using PHP, you can grab the data you want via:

```
preg_match_all('/<span class=".*?egg.*?">(.+?)<\/span>/',$text_you_got,$matches);
```

Testing code:

```
$text_you_got = 'I ate a <span class="egg">boiled egg</span> and <span class="ham">ham</span>.I ate a <span class="egg ham">ham and eggs</span>.';
preg_match_all('/<span class=".*?egg.*?">(.+?)<\/span>/',$text_you_got,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Results:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(35) "<span class="egg">boiled egg</span>"
    [1]=>
    string(78) "<span class="ham">ham</span>.I ate a <span class="egg ham">ham and eggs</span>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "boiled egg"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "ham and eggs"
  }
```

}

As shown, you can simply get the the result you want by:

```
$text_you_got = 'I ate a <span class="egg">boiled egg</span> and <span class="ham">ham</span>.I ate a <span class="egg ham">ham and eggs</span>.';
preg_match_all('/<span class=".*?egg.*?">(.+?)<\/span>/',$text_you_got,$matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $item)
{
    echo $item."\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
However, the results are not as expected.
Here are the search results.

`<span class="egg">boiled egg</span>`
`<span class="egg ham">ham and eggs</span>`

Comment: Yes, it match the whole pattern, but what you need is do get the capture group of this RegEx.

Comment: The answer you want is actually in the array $matches. The $matches contained items of the capture group targeted

Comment: This can give you more information about capture groups: https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/regex-capturing-groups/

Comment: I've updated the answer, pls review if you can get your expected answer now :)

Comment: I actually ran the source code you taught me in PHP, and it worked!
It seemed to be a problem with my text editor.
Thank you very much!